# Best way to canvas drawing in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, memory-management, xamarin.android

I have a single Android View and i will draw set of canvas drawings (text drawing) in the same view.

Now, I have a situation split those drawings in a separate views. Each text drawing will be in each view. So the number of child views will be the number of text.

Due to this changes, Can anyone tell me it will have any performance or memory  will be added in the application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And then, you will combine these child views to one view?

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT Yes. I will add all these child views in one view

Comment: Lets assume that you custom three view,View-A:textA,View-B:textB,View-C:textC, and then you use a `LinearLayout` to combine the three views by `AddView`, there is no performance or memory problem. You need tell us how you will combine these views.

Comment: Thanks @JoeLv-MSFT. We will add a text in any location in the view. Since we will add 100 views in a linear layout/FrameLayout, we have raised question for any memory or performance problem while adding 100 views

Comment: This demand is similar with an App which I have done last year, don't worry about the memory, the text drawing just a object, it will be released by GC if it is out of its scope. And about the performance, my app worke'd very smooth.

Comment: I suggest you do it firstly, if there is problem, find the problem and solve it.

Comment: Thanks @JoeLv-MSFT..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167416/discussion-between-venkydhana-and-joe-lv-msft).